# Longest running query per database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
ORDER BY
    s.max_elapsed_time DESC
```

to get the longest running queries on the server level.

How do I get the longest running queries per database? I would like to focus only on one database at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BOL entry for [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741(SQL.90).aspx) mentions [`sys.dm_exec_query_plan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747(SQL.90).aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
    CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
    CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) foo
WHERE
    foo.dbid = DB_ID('My_DB')
ORDER BY
    s.max_elapsed_time DESC
```

Edit: I've not tried it. I generally worry about server load...

Comment: Just keep in mind that if a query crosses multiple databases with joins, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM database1.dbo.table JOIN database2.dbo.table
```

In which database did the query above run? What if the current context at the moment of execution was database3? What if it was executed once in database4 and once in database5?

The idea is that execution plans are not tied to a database.

Comment: Presumably he either doesn't have any of these cross-database queries, or he doesn't care about them.

Comment: Hi, I want to look at all queries that belong to one database. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to tune the databases. Your longest running queries may not be your costliest ones, or the ones that you will benefit from the most.

You should read up on the SQL Server Profiler to identify the queries that use the most resources and work on them.